# How to disable captive.apple.com?

Tags: macos, wifi

I used a crummy AT&T (*coughAT&Tsymbollookslikedeathstarcough*) router to build a private LAN.  It has no service/DSL connections, there for it detects no internet access (naturally) and will give me this pop-up on a Mac:

[image: Pop-up on Mac]

This, as you can see, seems to be a Safari window of sorts that is sourcing captive.apple.com.  Because I have no DSL connection, all DNS resolutions get translated to the router's web host.  This means that every 5 to 10 minutes I get this pop-up.  The WiFi connection does work, but I get this annoying pop-up that interrupts my work.

On an iPhone, I have a similarish problem, although it is more consequential.  In Settings --> Wireless it gives me this same page asking me to Log In.  I assume that's the function of captive.apple.com.  I know places like McDonalds or Starbucks will do this to make sure you come in and buy something before getting on their WiFi.

My Question is this:  How do I disable this on a Mac so that I don't have to worry with this pop-up anymore?  The iPhone is a secondary problem, but it would be nice to have a solution for it.  Would a /etc/hosts entry fix it, or is it more complicated than that?

OS X version 10.11 El Capitan
2011 Mac Mini

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's 3 ways.

1. `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.captive.control Active -boolean false`
2. Just delete (or rename) `/System/Library/CoreServices/Captive Network Assistant.app`
3. Add an entry in `/etc/hosts` containing `127.0.0.1 captive.apple.com`

Comment: And it should actually be `127.0.0.1 captive.apple.com`

Comment: And the /etc/hosts entry did not work

Comment: The defaults write didn't work

Comment: Error: `sudo mv "/System/Library/CoreServices/Captive Network Assistant.app" "/System/Library/CoreServices/.Captive Network Assistant.app"
mv: rename /System/Library/CoreServices/Captive Network Assistant.app to /System/Library/CoreServices/.Captive Network Assistant.app: Operation not permitted`

Comment: So none of these worked

Comment: @Daniel Are you on El Capitan? If so, you'll need to [disable System Integrity Protection](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/) before messing with the System files.

Comment: Yes I am.  I should have put that in the Q.

Comment: I'll do that as soon as I finish classes for today (online high school classes for most of the day).

Comment: Note that this will not address the iPhone at all.

Comment: It looks like com.apple.captive.control was renamed at some point. On macOS 10.14.6 Mojave, it's called com.apple.captive.probe.plist