# Mac won't open the website 192.168.1.1 (MacOS Big Sur)

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

I need to have access to the website **192.168.1.1** to connect to my wifi but I can't open this website on my MacBook only (I could access it on my iPad). I tried using google chrome, safari and Microsoft Edge but none of these browsers could open this website.
I tried checking my proxies but all proxies were already unchecked.

Comment: What do you mean with "can't open"? Does the browser just show an empty page or do you get an error message of some kind? If you open Terminal and run `ping 192.168.1.1` what is shown as result?

Comment: Please check it precisely that if your MacBook is connected to the wi-fi correctly? First, check the network at the top right corner of your screen, then open the terminal as @nohillside said, and do the ping operation. The output of your screen is the key, please consider a short piece of that, then we can help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Open in InPrivate Browsing/Incognito mode and see if that helps.

Comment: Are you saying you have custom networking set up on this Mac, including specific proxies?

Answer (score 1):

You’ve got quite a catch-22 if you want the network to work before you can connect to your network. Big Sur is well tested with private non-routable networks like 192.168.X.X and since they are non-routable, you really need to get into the specifics of the local network to solve these.

1. You’ll need access to the router to examine and configure or change or (or access to a person that can do that for you)
2. You’ll need to learn a bit about routers and netmasks if the DHCP setup doesn’t work or your local and non-reputable network isn’t flat with all the machines in the same small address pool.

What are your options to manage this network or get help? Since none of that detail is on your question, we’re not going to be of any use solving your network remotely. Especially if this network has a [captive portal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211593/how-to-disable-captive-apple-com), you may be stuck if you don’t try to open this site in your browsers one by one.

- http://captive.apple.com